# Отладка без исходников

Tags: отладка, visual-studio, ассемблер, visual-studio-2010

Как посмотреть или сделать лог вызовов от breakpoint до breakpoint, лучше второе.

Если можно с параметрами из стека.

При attach-е к запущенному приложению в Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Без исходников вы даже брейкпоинты расставить не сможете (если вам заранее не известны соответствующие адреса). Если как-то и расставите, отладка ассемблерного кода в студии - удовольствие ниже среднего, она не для этого предназначена.

Используйте специализированные инструменты: OllyDbg или IDA (для 64-битных приложений).